# How can I pass parameters to a jQuery $.getJSON callback method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm trying to use jQuery to call some custom API via `Ajax/$.getJSON`.

I'm trying to pass a custom value into the Ajax callback method, but that value is not getting passed through and is actually getting overwritten. This is my code:

```
var locationType = 3;
var url = 'blah blah blah' + '&locationType=' + locationType;

$("#loading_status").show();

$.getJSON(url, null, function(results, locationType) {
    searchResults(results, locationType)
});
```

The value of `locationType` BEFORE I call the URL using AJAX is `3`. But after the call returns the data successfully, the value for `locationType` is now `success`. This is because the [method signature of the callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is:

> callback(data, textStatus)A callback
>   function that is executed if the
>   request succeeds.

How can I pass 1 or more parameters to a callback method?

Comment: locationType variable is global variable so you don't need to put it as parameter, in anonimus callback function that variable is free so it is search in surrounding environment which in this case is global environment.

Comment: @jcubic - It's not a *global* variable (well it might be, but probably not), more accurately it's available in the scope he's concerned about.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to pass it in, just reference the variable you already have, like this:

```
var locationType = 3;
var url = 'blah blah blah' + '&locationType=' + locationType;
$("#loading_status").show();
$.getJSON(url, null, function(results) {
    searchResults(results, locationType)
});
```

Also there's no need to pass `null` if you don't have a data object, it's an optional parameter and jQuery checks if the second param is a function or not, so you can just do this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(results) {
    searchResults(results, locationType)
});
```

Comment: You must be careful with this. For a fixed value variable this is useful, but if you try to do this, for example, inside a loop where locationType is the index, its value inside the callback will be the value at the moment of the callback execution, not the value at definition. Just in case!

Comment: @DanibISHOP: And how would you pass a none fixed value?

Comment: non fixed values might be usefull if you do a lot of API calls and then still need to know which call originated from which ID you are loading

Answer (score 19):

Warp in a function, e.g.

```
function getResults(locationType) {
    $.getJSON(url, null, function(results) {
        searchResults(results, locationType)
    });
}
```

But in you specific situation you don't even have to pass it, you can access the value directly in the callback.

Comment: if you are doing a loop and calling $.getJSON() each time, then wrapping it a function will preserve the variable; otherwise, it will be overridden.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method:

```
var locationType = 3;
var url = 'blah blah blah' + '&locationType=' + locationType;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    context: { lt: locationType },
    success: function(results) {
        searchResults(results, this.lt);    
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe there is an error in the code above. When using the context setting, "this" becomes the context in the callback function, so the code should read searchResults(results, this.lt); instead of searchResults(results, this.context.lt);. I already made the correction above.

Comment: If this ajax call gets called multiple times (and possibly before the previous call returns), then this is the only correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `locationType` (whose value is `3`) in the callback, simply use

```
function(results) { .....
```

thanks to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), `locationType` will be automatically available in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
function getResults(locationType) {
    $.getJSON(url, {p1:'xxx', p2: 'yyy'}, function(results) {
        searchResults(results, locationType)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("url",
        "//here you can define your id, secure key to check data in your console, if you don't have condition for id and secure key just remove the secure key part."
        {secure_key:"noaccess"}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
});
```